# PLSQL compare and assign values based on MAX stockcount

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a requirement to assign GRP numbers to the stores having sum(stockcount) just upto value 110000, as described in the image. Means the GRP numbers are incremented by 1 as soon as the sum of stockcount reaches upto or crosses 110000, after which next stock numbers are allotted.

Please see the image below.

[Stock-Store Max count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFbMh.png)
this code dosen't seem to do as per what is needed.

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET TIMING ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
SET LINESIZE 200
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET VERIFY OFF

VARIABLE return_code NUMBER

DECLARE

   v_pg        sku.u_pg%TYPE;
   v_count     NUMBER := 0;
   v_aggcount  NUMBER := 0;
   v_value     NUMBER := 1;

   CURSOR cur_upd_optinv_label
   IS
      SELECT /*+ Parallel (64) */ 
            LOCATION, 
            count(*) as STOCK_COUNT
        FROM sku 
        GROUP BY LOCATION 
        order by count(*) desc;

BEGIN

   BEGIN

      FOR vll_use IN cur_upd_optinv_label

      LOOP
         v_pg := vll_use.LOCATION;
         v_count := vll_use.stockcount;
         v_aggcount := v_aggcount + v_count;

         IF v_aggcount <= 110000

         THEN

            UPDATE the GRP column  = v_value where location = v_pg;

        ELSE

            v_value := v_value + 1;

            UPDATE the GRP column  = v_value where location = v_pg;

            v_aggcount := v_count;

      EXIT WHEN v_aggcount = 11;
      END IF;
      END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         RAISE;
   END;

COMMIT;
   :return_code := 0;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      :return_code := 3;
ROLLBACK;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Error encountered: ' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/

EXIT :return_code
```

Comment: Please don't paste pictures. User formatted text for input and output data.

Comment: Having `UPDATE` without any WHERE condition seems to be useless.

Comment: have added the where condition

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please review the help section [ask]. Following that as a template for your question gives you a much better chance of getting a successful answer. In this case in particular we need sample data - as text, the expected results, and the table DDL.

Comment: Check the code line `EXIT WHEN v_aggcount = 11;` that might be causing the problem. Also please share the current behaviour of the script

Answer (score 0):

i hope this could help you.

```
declare 
l_val number(10):=1;
l_agg_cnt number(10):=0;
l_loc sku.location%type;
l_msg varchar2(200);

cursor c_sku_info is 
             select location, stock from sku
                order by stock desc;
Begin
for idx in c_sku_info 
loop
--dbms_output.put_line(idx.stck_cnt);
l_loc:=idx.location;
l_agg_cnt:=l_agg_cnt+idx.stock;
--dbms_output.put_line(l_agg_cnt);
if (l_agg_cnt<=110000 or l_agg_cnt >= 110000) then
update sku set grp=l_val 
where location=l_loc;
dbms_output.put_line(l_val||' '||l_agg_cnt);
--commit;
end if ;
 if l_agg_cnt >= 110000 then 
           l_val:=l_val+1;
           l_agg_cnt:=0;
          end if;
end loop;
exception
when others then
l_msg:=DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @srinu nivas may be satisfactory but there are 2 issues: The if condition (l_agg_cnt<=110000 or l_agg_cnt >= 110000) will always return True (unless l_agg_cnt is null). Also there cursor assumes there is a single row for ech location. This however is not clear from the description. Which is severely lacking, you would do well the review the help section [How_to_Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

While PL/SQL in capable in general it's better to let SQL do the heavy lifting - as much of the work as possible. In this case a single statement is possible. It combines Merge with a recursive CTE. (Note: It does not require a single row for each location.)

```
merge into sku
using (with loc  as
          --- get location and total stock count ordering by total and gererate id 
          ( select location, stock_count, rownum row_id 
              from (select location, stock_count  
                      from (select location, sum(stock_count) stock_count
                              from sku 
                             group by location
                           )   
                      order by stock_count desc
                   )
           )  
         -- Build recursive CTE 
         , grp (location,stock_count,group_count,grp,row_id ) as
                  --  Starting with id =1 from loc cte above and setting grp = 1
               ( select location,stock_count,stock_count,1,row_id
                   from loc  
                  where row_id = 1
                  -- now join each row 2-n from loc above and determining total stock for the group and assigning grp 
                 union all 
                 select loc.location,loc.stock_count
                        -- update grp and reset group total stock
                      , case when grp.group_count > 110000 then loc.stock_count else  grp.group_count + loc.stock_count end        
                      , case when grp.group_count > 110000 then grp.grp+1 else grp.grp end
                      , loc.row_id
                   from grp join loc on grp.row_id+1 = loc.row_id 
               ) 
               -- finally extract location and its assigned group
               select location, grp from grp) grp_set

      -- identify location and set grp (note updates all rows for location)
      on (grp_set.location = sku.location)
      when matched then
           update set grp = grp_set.grp;
```

--- Results
    select distinct 
           location
         , stock_count
         , grp
         , sum(stock_count) over(partition by grp)
      from (select location, grp, sum(stock_count) stock_count 
              from sku 
             where grp is not null
             group by location, grp
           )
    order by grp, location

;

Unfortunately, I was unable to test with your data as it was not provides as text. Good Luck